# CacheOverflowException at memory location 0x0039F318

Tags: c++, directx, direct2d

every time I call to transform render target in direct 2D I get this message:

```
pRenderTarget->SetTransform(any_matrix_other_than_identity);
```

> First-chance exception at 0x7612C42D in class window.exe: Microsoft
>   C++ exception: CacheOverflowException at memory location 0x0039F318.

Comment: The reality is, this could be anything. Start by adding the D2D debug layer to your device and it will give you a message on the output window of Visual Studio on what exactly is going on....or at least a better message than just a memory access error.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee794278(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is just an internal exception that's used for control flow. Add the exception to your ignore list.